# JS, Vue: how to split text based on window height?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have text that I want to split at a specific point so that you dont need to scroll down.

That means I want to know when the text gets longer than the availible height of the window. This needs to be known before I show the text. The problem with that is that I need to know how my layout will look like before I render it, because the whole thing should be responsive to width and height.

I also plan to resize the fontsizes a little. So taking all that to account, does anyone of you know of you know how to split the text at the correct point?

Thank you in advance.

PS: The text is actually an array and is looking like this for e.g.:

```
text = [{content: Hello, wordID: ..., offsetBegin: 0, offsetEnd: 5,
         ...},{content: World!, wordID: ..., offsetBeding: 7, offsetEnd: 12,...}]
```

So the only thing I need to know is the indexes on where to split the text so that there are no scrolbars on the main window. Splitting the text can occur more than once too.

The whole thing will start to be displayed and computed in the mounted() hook and will be recomputed each time the 'resize' event of for window is fired.

Comment: Is your textual content broken up into paragraphs or is it 1 really long text set that needs to be broken up completely?  I ask, because you can take a look at how Google deals with flowing paragraphs in [The Mobile Playbook](http://www.themobileplaybook.com/en-us/).  It looks like they duplicate paragraphs that will be split in half by a pagebreak and situate the duplicated paragraph at the top of the next page offset at where the original paragraph was cut off.

Comment: You just want to cut off the text? What are you going to do with the text that doesn't fit?

Comment: You can use [column-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width) along with setting the height, width, and overflow:hidden on a div to cause the text to column-wrap into invisible space.

Comment: @zero298 It one long array of text objects like described.

Comment: @Roy J I will have maximum 12 columns of text that I want to show. More than that will be stored in vue. I will have 2 buttons that will change the scope of the text, so that if I click "next" I will hide the first column of the text and show the next column that comes after the last one I currently show.

Comment: @Roy J I use material.io that should divide my view into columns. That means the columnwidth will be variable. also the line height, fontsize changes with the screensize. That why I find this task so tricky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This questions seems to have the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You might want to reconsider if this is really how you want to solve the problem.

However, if you really want to get the cutoff point in JS:

The height of the text depends on multiple things, such as the width of the element, the font size and -weight, the kerning, so on and so forth. There are a lot of variables to consider, and it's unlikely that you can do the calculations without rendering anything.

Instead, you should ask the browser to render your element, and then remove it before the rendering is shown to the user. This would be done by [forcing a reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) once you have inserted your text, measuring where the text should end, and then forcing a new reflow once you've removed your text.

The tricky part is measuring where the text should end. I would personally solve this by inserting elements at every position I want a cutoff to be possible at (e.g. after every word), and then looping through them to see which overflows the container.

---

Below is a vanilla JS implementation of the idea. You should be able to fairly easily implement it in Vue.

```js
const DEBUG = true;

const $textInp = document.getElementById("text-inp");
const $target = document.getElementById("target");
const $outp = document.getElementById("outp");

document.getElementById("calc-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const text = $textInp.value;
    const data = getTextCutoff(text, $target);
    $outp.textContent = JSON.stringify(data);
    if (!DEBUG) { $target.textContent = text.substr(0, data.end); }
});

/**
 * Returns an object of format { end: <Number> }
 * Where `end` is the last index which can be displayed inside $elm without overflow
 */
function getTextCutoff(text, $elm) {
    $elm.innerHTML = ""; // empty the element
    const prevOverflow = $elm.style.overflow;
    const prevPosition = $elm.style.position;
    $elm.style.overflow = "visible";
    $elm.style.position = "relative"; // to make sure offsetHeight gives relative to parent
    const $indicators = [];
    const $nodes = [];
    // turn our text into an array of text nodes, with an indicator node after each
    let currentIndex = 0;
    const words = text.split(" ");
    words.forEach(
        (word, i) => {
            if (i > 0) {
                word = " "+word;
            }
            currentIndex += word.length;
            const $wordNode = document.createTextNode(word);
            $nodes.push($wordNode);
            const $indicatorNode = document.createElement("span");
            $indicatorNode.strIndex = currentIndex;
            if (DEBUG) { $indicatorNode.classList.add("text-cutoff-indicator"); }
            $indicators.push($indicatorNode);
            $nodes.push($indicatorNode);
        }
    );
  
    // insert our elements
    $nodes.forEach($node => $elm.appendChild($node));
  
    // then find the first indicator that is overflown
    const maxHeight = $elm.offsetHeight;
    let $lastIndicator = $indicators[$indicators.length - 1];
    for (let i = 0; i < $indicators.length; ++i) {
       const $indicator = $indicators[i];
        const bottomPos = $indicator.offsetTop + $indicator.offsetHeight;
        if (bottomPos > maxHeight) {
            break;
        } else { $lastIndicator = $indicator; }
    }
  
    if (DEBUG) {
        $lastIndicator.style.borderColor = "green";
        $lastIndicator.classList.add("overflown");
    }
  
    // then reset everything - this also forces reflow
    if (!DEBUG) { $elm.innerHTML = ""; }
    $elm.style.overflow = prevOverflow;
    $elm.style.position = prevPosition;
  
    // then return
    return {
        end: $lastIndicator.strIndex
    };
}
```

```css
#target {
  height: 128px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.text-cutoff-indicator {
  margin-left: -2px;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
}

.text-cutoff-indicator.overflown ~ .text-cutoff-indicator {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="text-inp" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
  <button id="calc-btn">Apply text</button>
  <pre id="outp"></pre>
</div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I need a little time to "translate" and test it. I have one question though: If I have long texts, is it possible that I run into scalability issues? Since you loop over every word. Can I do the same thing with lines or something?

Comment: @telion Absolutely. Note that it will decrease the accuracy, as the returned index will be the last indicator that doesn't overflow (so it will be at the end of the last visible line, even if part of the next line is visible) - but that's something you'll have to weigh depending on how much you value accuracy vs. performance.

Comment: About the XY-Problem:

Comment: About the XY-Problem: Of course I can try to explain every Layer of my "Problem", but I that would mean I need to explain a lot of the infrastructure of my project. So Im a little confused to declare the right "X" in this case. But to go on a deeper level: Its about displaying a text on very big screens without the need to scroll. But I know already on how to show the text columns, so thats not really the X. The Problem was that I didnt know where to split the text to distribute the text among the columns.

Comment: So I had a problem where most of the parts of the solution where already clear except for one that I asked about. (have different columns to use all the free space, content of the columns beside the text, design of the content, distribution/splitting of text,... was part of problem X, but only the textsplitting didnt work, so it was my new X). So Im a little confused on how to avoid the XY-Problem in this case

Comment: @telion In general, you want to explain your problem, not ask how to implement the solution. In this case you would've explained that you have some text that you want to display without scrolling, by splitting it up into columns. It would then be up to the answerer to figure out a solution, whether that be JS or CSS based. This would allow you to get solutions that you hadn't thought of before you asked the question.